# Remote notification couldn't be received with TestFlight distribution

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I can receive remote notifications with installation of Development and AdHoc Distribution(Over the air with my server). However, when I use TestFlight in iTunes Connect to install app, the app can't receive notifications with Provisioning Profiles of App Store or Ad Hoc Distribution(both have been tested). I also tested sending notifications to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com and gateway.push.apple.com, both failed. Does anyone confront the same problem?

Comment: Yes I just noticed the same problem with test flight in itunesconnect

Comment: Did you try to change the server to Production mode?(Just the push notification I mean)